# Divide, sum values in computed column specification

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a table where I need to calculate average time between trip using the following values.

```
Date        Clockin       CLockout        Trip1           Trip2
====        =======       ========        =====           ======
01/01/2013   13:00        17:00            3               3
```

I tried this.

```
(datediff(minute,[Clockin],[ClockOut])/case when [Trip1]=(0) then NULL else [Trip1] end+case when [Trip2]=(0) then NULL else [Trip2] end)
```

and

```
(datediff(minute,[Clockin],[ClockOut])/case when [Trip1]=(0) then 1 else [Trip1] end+case when [Trip2]=(0) then 1 else [Trip2] end)
```

The objective is to calculate the duration between trips.  ie, 4 hours / 3 trips  if trip2 is null otherwise 4 hours / 3 + 3 (4 hours / 6 trips)

But the above don't seem to produce the correct result.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: shouldn't that be `case when NULL then`, because I'm pretty sure you can't divide by `NULL`

Comment: @WimOmbelets: Quite the opposite. Dividing by NULL results in NULL, as indeed other operations with NULL (addition, subtraction, multiplication, most, if not all, arithmetic function calls). It is a convenient trick to substitute a potential 0 divisor with a NULL to cause the entire result to be NULL (and process it at a later stage, possibly).

Comment: thanks @AndriyM , that's useful knowledge to have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how you wish to deal with a trip sum of 0 (is it a null result?), one of the following calculations should work:

```
declare @t table ([Date] date, Clockin time, CLockout time, Trip1 int, Trip2 int)
insert into @t  

    select '01/01/2013', '13:00', '17:00', 3, 3 union all
    select '01/01/2013', '13:00', '17:00', 0, 3 union all
    select '01/01/2013', '13:00', '17:00', 0, 0 union all
    select '01/01/2013', '13:00', '17:00', 3, null;

select  [minutes]=datediff(mi, Clockin, Clockout), 
        [trips] = ((isnull(Trip1, 0)+isnull(Trip2,0))),
        [calc] = datediff(mi, Clockin, Clockout)/ (nullif((isnull(Trip1, 0)+isnull(Trip2,0)), 0)),
        [calc2] = datediff(mi, Clockin, Clockout)/ isnull((nullif((isnull(Trip1, 0)+isnull(Trip2,0)), 0)), 1)
from @t
```

Comment: Cool..  That works!..  Thanks!!..  and have gathered much useful knowledge from all solutions..  Thanks to you all!!..

Answer (score 0):

```
CASE WHEN trip2 IS NULL 
     THEN DATEDIFF(hour,[Clockin],[ClockOut]) / Trip1 
     ELSE (DATEDIFF(hour,[Clockin],[ClockOut]) / Trip1 + Trip2) 
        * (DATEDIFF(hour,[Clockin],[ClockOut]) + (Trip1 + Trip2)) 
END
```

Comment: I tried your solution and it seems to give me the correct result, but when I input zero, I get a divided by zero error same goes for the other answer which I can also place in a computed column spec..

Comment: what shall be result if I input zero?

Comment: The user may change from 3 to zero to remove previous input.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT 
  CONVERT(Decimal, DateDiff(hh,ClockIn,ClockOut)) / 
  CASE 
    WHEN Trip1 IS NULL AND Trip2 IS NULL THEN 1
    ELSE CONVERT(Decimal, (COALESCE(Trip1,0) + COALESCE(Trip1,0)))
  END as result
FROM YourTable
```

I wasn't sure what you wanted if both Trip1 and Trip2 were NULL, but I added a CASE statement to divide by 1 instead.

And here is the [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6ec61/3).

Good luck.